# Como converter uma variavel data para o formato brasileiro dentro de uma view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Dentro de uma `index.blade.php` tenho uma variável:

```
<td>{{$ordemjoin->dataplanejamento}}</td>
```

Na listagem sai a data no formato *Inglês*. Como eu faço para colocar no formato *Brasileiro*?

<sub>**Observação:**  versão do `Laravel 5.2`</sub>

Comment: o retorno de `$ordemjoin->dataplanejamento` é datetime?

Comment: você usa a assim `DB::select('select * from users where id = :id', ['id' => 1]);` pra trazer dados???

Comment: Sim eu uso DB. Ainda não sei como funciona o eloquent corretamente então faço os joins

Comment: @MarcosBirro eu fiz uma resposta por acaso ajudou, ou não?

Comment: Ajudou sim. Vou usar o helpers.

Comment: @MarcosBirro um pergunta tem algum problema nas respostas dadas que você não aceita como respostas? vi na sua página que nunca deu

Comment: Eu aceitei todas. Não estou vendo nenhuma que não respondi Todas estão me ajudando..

Comment: Aceitar é colocar check verdinho na parte inferior da seta e pontuar com um voto se assim quiser. Na sua pagina estão sem.

Comment: Claro. Seria otimo.

Comment: Verdade @MarcosBirro se você puder e quiser ler esses [link 1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers),  [link 2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) e [link 3](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assim deve funcionar:

```
   <td>{{ date( 'd/m/Y' , strtotime($ordemjoin->dataplanejamento))}}</td>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54191/discussion-on-answer-by-mau-humor-como-converter-uma-variavel-data-para-o-format)

Answer (score 3):

Com o uso somente da classe [***DB***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database) não tem todos os recursos oferecidos pelo [***Eloquent***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent), então, faça direto na `SQL`: `DATE_FORMAT(dataplanejamento,'%d/%m/%Y') as dataplanejamentobr`

```
DB::select("SELECT tabela.*, 
         DATE_FORMAT(dataplanejamento,'%d/%m/%Y') as dataplanejamentobr from tabela");
```

---

```
<td>{{$ordemjoin->dataplanejamentobr}}</td>
```

Se ainda não quiser fazer assim pode trabalhar com [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) com [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), mas, cria um arquivo de `helpers` e coloque uma função para não ficar repetindo código:

```
function date_br($value, $format='d/m/Y')
{
   return date($format, strtotime($value));
}
```

e na [***Views***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views) ([`blade`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)):

```
<td>{{date_br($carros->dataplanejamento)}}</td>
```

---

***Recomendação:***

Se você começar usar o [***Eloquent***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) vai perceber o ganho de programação em relação a usar a classe [***DB***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database) um exemplo claro que vou ilustrar seria o [***Date Mutators***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) na configuração da classe, ***exemplo***:

No `array` de `$dates` insira o campo `date` ou `datetime` em seu caso `dataplanejamento`:

```
class Carros extends Model
{    
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at',
        'dataplanejamento'
    ];
}
```

no seu arquivo da [***Views***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views) ([`blade`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)) poderia fazer direto assim:

```
<td>{{$carros->dataplanejamento->format('d/m/Y')}}</td>
```

seria muito fácil e poderia formatar a sua data.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)
- [DB](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database)
- [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)
- [Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views)
- [Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade)

Answer (score 1):

voce pode usar casts passando na sua model ele retorna a data no formato correto

```
protected $casts = [
    'dataplanejamento' => 'datetime:d/m/Y',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente pelo que descreve na pergunta e nos comentários, o objeto deve ser uma string. Nesse caso o exemplo abaixo deve resolver:

```
{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($ordemjoin->dataplanejamento)->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

Se o objeto for um `Carbon`, basta invocar o método `format()` diretamente do próprio objeto.

```
{{$ordemjoin->dataplanejamento->format('d/m/Y')}}
```

Comment: Substitui a linha por esta:
{{Carbon\Carbon::parse($ordemjoin->dataplanejamento)->format('d/m/Y')}}
Resultado: Não trouxe nada. Talvez o Carbon não esteja instalado. Tem como saber?

Comment: Estou usando o vagrant ok?